# New Relic Scripted Browser sendKeys is sending keys out of order

Tags: newrelic, scriptedbrowser

I am using New Relic's Scripted Browser to populate a form.  When I use the sendKeys method to send a phone number or a zip code, sometimes the keys are send out of order.  For example:

```
.then(function () {
log(6.7, 'Populate Zip')
$browser.sleep("8000");
return $browser.waitForAndFindElement(By.id("shippingZip"))
.then(function (el) {
el.clear();//clear out the input
el.sendKeys("12345");
```

What is sent to the browser is "12453"

Has anyone experienced this problem before?